# Complex differentiability of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = 8e^{3iz^2}$ be a complex function. Where is it differentiable?

By applying Cauchy-Riemann, I ended up with the equations

$y\cos(3x^2-3y^2) = x\sin(3x^2-3y^2)$

$-x\cos(3x^2-3y^2) = y\sin(3x^2-3y^2)$

Is the computation correct so far? And, if so, how do I find all the roots of this? Thanks!

Comment: It isn't right.  The function is differentiable everywhere, but the first equation is not satisfied when $x=y=1$.  Please show your work, so we can spot the error? Guess: you said $z^2=x^2-y^2$ instead of $z^2=x^2+2ixy-y^2$

Comment: @saulspatz I wrote $ f(z) = e^{3i((x^2-y^2)+2xyi)} = e^{-6xy +3(x^2-y^2)i} = 8e^{-6xy}cos(3x^2-3y^2) + 8e^{-6xy}sin(3x^2-3y^2)i = u(x,y) + v(x,y)i$, but maybe there is something wrong with my partial derivatives.

Comment: It should be $e^{+6xy}$, but there's probably another error after that.  BTW, your expression will look better if you write `$\cos$` and `$\sin$` instead of `$cos$` and `$sin$`.

Comment: A suggestion:  please show all your steps.  You can write this as part of the question, or as an answer.  Folks here will be happy to show you where the mistake (if any) is.  What is $u(x,y)$, $v(x,y)$, $u_x(x,y), u_y(x,y), v_x(x,y), v_y(x,y)$?

Comment: So by applying CR I end up with the following equations for the partial derivatives: $ 8(e^{xy}ycos(3x^2-3y^2)-6e^{xy}xsin(3x^2-3y^2) = 8(e^{xy}xsin(3x^2-3y^2)-6e^{xy}ycos(3x^2-3y^2)$ and $ 8(e^{xy}ysin(3x^2-3y^2)+6e^{xy}xcos(3x^2-3y^2) = 8(e^{xy}xcos(3x^2-3y^2)+6e^{xy}ysin(3x^2-3y^2)$. I guess I should get identical sides on both equations, but I 've done this like 3 times and still cannot spot the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x+iy) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=8 \exp(-6xy) [\cos 3(x^2-y^2) +i\sin 3(x^2-y^2)].$$

$$\begin{aligned}
u_x&= -48 \exp(-6xy) [ y \cos 3(x^2-y^2) + x \sin 3(x^2-y^2)],\\
u_y&= -48 \exp(-6xy) [ x \cos 3(x^2-y^2) - y \sin 3(x^2-y^2)],\\ 
v_x&=\phantom{-}48 \exp(-6xy) [ x \cos 3(x^2-y^2) - y \sin 3(x^2-y^2)],\\ 
v_y&= -48 \exp(-6xy) [ y \cos 3(x^2-y^2) + x \sin 3(x^2-y^2)].\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned} u_x&=\phantom{-}v_y \\ u_y &= -v_x\end{aligned}$$

The functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations everywhere.  The function $f=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$ is entire.

Answer (score 0):

You can always resort to checking the Cauchy-Riemann (CR) equations for $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ or $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$.

We see immediately that $f(z) = 8e^{3iz^2}$ is entire (holomorphic or differentiable everywhere) because it is the composition of entire functions.

$g(z)=z^2$ is entire (easy to check with CR).

$h(z)=\alpha \cdot z$ is entire (obviously, please check it).

$m(z)=e^z$ is entire (easy to check with CR).

$$f(z) = h(m(h(g(z)))).$$

Comment: I see, I will resort to this if I cannot make the original equations work. Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you can get the original equations to work out!  Apply the chain rule, carefully!

Comment: I've written my calculations above, on saulspatz's comment, can you please take a look?

Comment: You should have $f(x+iy) = 8 \exp(-6xy) [\cos[3(x^2-y^2)] +i \sin[3(x^2-y^2)] ]$.  Do you?